# Who is Brett White and why was he a moderator?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, editing

Who is Brett White?

- Is he an employee of Stack Exchange?
- Does that tiny psi/fork/trident in his username mean he's part of CHAOS?
- Is he going through highly viewed questions and editing their titles into (hopefully) easily searchable and readable complete sentences?
- Does he have to have sideburns?

The answer to all of those questions...is **yes**. Hello! Don't be alarmed by the potentially large amount of title edits I'll be doing over the next few days while I have temporary moderator powers. And please change/undo my edits if you notice that an old title was better or that my edit mangles or leaves out some key information. I trust your judgment on these matters!

Thanks, and I am sure we will be "seeing" more of each other!

Comment: I've now seen a couple forky folks who mention "CHAOS" in all caps. What does that mean? Is that an acronym? Secret society? Are you literally just wreaking havoc?

Comment: @sjohnston They're pretty much doing exactly what Brett says he's doing here, on other sites.

Comment: @sjohnston: The forky folks are here to serve, clearly.

Comment: As I understand it (from the SE Podcast) the CHAOS team is about community outreach and encouraging development.

Comment: This should really be broken up into a question and answer. Someone from CHAOS get onto this.

Comment: The forky folks aren't really folks at all, are they. ARE THEY? *dons tin-foil hat*

Comment: Posting this on all the CHAOS monkey's intro posts ;) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1461365#1461365

Comment: [Official Joel announcement of CHAOS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character)

Comment: Ahh, I was wondering *who you were*. Great work on the question cleanup!

Comment: You don't seem to be a moderator anymore, is that intended?

Comment: Yes, our mod privileges were only intended to last for a brief time.

Answer (score 8):

[Here is a post about CHAOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character), direct from Joel himself. It has a lot of info about what our job is, as well as a picture of us. I am the one that looks like me, just without my glasses.